# Which thread async operations take place

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

Afte reading the asio's documentation, it's clear to me that the completion handlers are called by one of the threads that called the io_service's  `io.run()` method. However, something that's is not clear to me is which thread the read/write async methods take place. Is it the thread that I call the methods or is it in one of the threads that called the `io.run()` method? Or, in last case, does the library create another thread behind the scenes and performs the operation?

Comment: Is this because you want to know if it blocks some operation, or because you want to know what state the thread local variables are in, or some other purpose?

Comment: It's because I am developing a critical application and I cannot afford to waste time writing on the thread that my application is running. I know I can post a lambda do my io_service in order to write operation take place on one of the threads that called the run() method. However, if the library itself create a thread another thread to perform the write operation, it wouldn't be necessary to post to the io_service.

Comment: The [Platform-Specific Implementation Notes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/implementation.html) documentation notes the creation and purpose of all internal threads.  None of the internal threads will service write operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance, you want to send some data to a remote-partner - asynchronous.

```
boost::asio::async_write(_socket, boost::asio::buffer(msg.data(), msg.size()),
    std::bind(&Socket::WriteHandlerInternal, this->shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
//Where 'this' is the class Socket
```

Before that, you probably have created a thread which called `ioService.run()`. The `async_write` function will take the same `ioService` you have used to create your socket. It puts it into the queue of your `ioService` to execute the write operation and the handler - **on the thread your `ioService` runs on, as the `async_` already suggests.**

Comment: That's what I was suspecting. However, since I haven't seen this explicitly on the boost documentation, I didn't want to make any assumption.

Answer (score 1):

The I/O operation will be attempted within the initiating `async_*` function.  If either the operation's completion condition is satisfied or an error occurs, then the operation is complete and the completion handler will be posted into the `io_service`.  Otherwise, the operation is not complete, and it will be enqueued into the `io_service`, where an application thread running the `io_service`'s function `poll()`, `poll_one()`, `run()`, or `run_one()` performs the underlying I/O operation.  In both cases, the completion handler is invoked by a thread processing the `io_service`.

The [`async_write()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html) documentation notes that the asynchronous operation may be completed immediately:

> Regardless of whether the asynchronous operation completes immediately or not, the handler will not be invoked from within this function. Invocation of the handler will be performed in a manner equivalent to using `boost::asio::io_service::post()`.

This behavior is also noted in the [Requirements on Asynchronous Operations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asynchronous_operations.html) documentation:

> When an asynchronous operation is complete, the handler for the operation will be invoked as if by:
>
> - Constructing a bound completion handler `bch` for the handler ...
> - Calling `ios.post(bch)` to schedule the handler for deferred invocation ...
>
> This implies that the handler must not be called directly from within the initiating function, even if the asynchronous operation completes immediately.

---

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/831e5b3a6d18adbe) this behavior.  In it, `socket1` and `socket2` are connected.  Initially, `socket2` has no data available.  However, after invoking `async_write(socket1, ...)`, `socket2` has data even though the `io_service` has not been ran:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

constexpr auto noop = [](auto&& ...){};

int main()
{
  using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  // Create all I/O objects.
  tcp::acceptor acceptor{io_service, {{}, 0}};
  tcp::socket socket1{io_service};
  tcp::socket socket2{io_service};

  // Connect sockets.
  acceptor.async_accept(socket1, noop);
  socket2.async_connect(acceptor.local_endpoint(), noop);
  io_service.run();
  io_service.reset();

  // Verify socket2 has no data.
  assert(0 == socket2.available());

  // Initiate an asynchronous write.  However, do not run
  // the `io_service`.
  std::string data{"example"};
  async_write(socket1, boost::asio::buffer(data), noop);

  // Verify socket2 has data.
  assert(0 < socket2.available());
}
```